# Can't figure out how to get shadows to work with react-three-fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I've been following some tutorials to make this simple sandbox with a test .glb file.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-black-et9cs?file=/src/App.js

Everything seems to work except the shadows. I can't find any missing castShadow/recieveShadow/shadowMap declarations anywhere... just not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks if you can point to my mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the shadow map size to such a high value is no good approach since it's bad for performance.

Instead, decrease the frustum of the shadow camera. Use the following values:

```
shadow-camera-near={0.1}
shadow-camera-far={20}
shadow-camera-left={-10}
shadow-camera-right={10}
shadow-camera-top={10}
shadow-camera-bottom={-10}
```

Keep in mind that you can visually debug and thus better optimize the shadow camera by using [THREE.CameraHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=camera#api/en/helpers/CameraHelper).

Comment: Hm, I tried adjusting those values on my sandbox directionalLight and they did not fix the no-shadow-display issue.

Comment: It did work for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-rain-zuzy8

Comment: Ohh the codesandbox just doesn't really seem to live refresh shadows (I have to refresh the output). so perhaps this entire question was a non-issue to start with. Thanks for helping me Mugen.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - it was the shadow-mapSize-width and height. 1024 wasn't enough, I had to bump that number much bigger (works at 10240). Not sure why this is the case, perhaps my imported model is of a different scale or something. But it works now!